# Is there a theorem about $|x^a-y^b|$ growing as $a,b$ grow?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I accidentally stumbled on a convoluted proof that Fibonacci numbers grow arbitrarily far from the nearest higher power of 2.

More precisely, for any $c$, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $$2^{\lceil\log_2 F_n\rceil}-F_n>c.$$

I assume therefore that this is not a surprising result, but am wondering whether this is due to some peculiarity with the Fibonacci numbers, or if there is a general theorem covering the behavior of  $|x^a-y^b|$ for a fixed $x,y$ as $a,b$ grow without bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One result of this ilk is [Baker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem): if $\{\lambda_j\}_j$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\{\beta_j\}_j$ are algebraic numbers of height at most $H$, then there is a constant $C$ such that $$\left|\sum_j{\beta_j\lambda_j}\right|>H^{-C}$$

To see the connection, take the $2$-term case $$a\log{(x)}-b\log{(y)}>H^{-C}$$ and exponentiate: $$\frac{x^a}{y^b}>e^{H^{-C}}$$  Thus $$x^a>y^be^{H^{-C}}$$  For arge $a,b$, $H$ is also large, so $e^{H^{-C}}$ is roughly $1$…say, $e^{H^{-C}}=1+\epsilon$.  (If we trust a Taylor expansion, then $\epsilon=H^{-C}+o(H^{-C})$.)  Then $$x^a>y^b+\epsilon y^b$$  Rearranging, $$x^a-y^b>\epsilon y^b$$

This shows that we have in fact an *exponential* growth in the difference between two such powers.

H/T [Terry Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/hilberts-seventh-problem-and-powers-of-2-and-3/)